# SOQL Query for custom Lightning Component

Tags: apex

I'm within a custom object (called Funding Source) that has a Master relationship with Opportunity. I'm trying to query from another custom object (called Personal Guarantor) and display certain fields from Personal Guarantor in the Funding Source object.

Right now my code is:

```
public with sharing class DS_PGinFundingSource {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<PersonalGuarantor__c> getPGs() {
    Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.DBA__c, Account.St_Incorp__c, Account.FederalTaxID__c, 
                        Account.Phone, Account.NAICS_Code__c, Account.BusinessStructure__c, Account.Mo_Year_business_started__c, 
                        Account.ShippingStreet, Account.ShippingCity, Account.ShippingState, Account.ShippingPostalCode, 
                        Account.BillingStreet, Account.BillingCity, Account.BillingState, Account.BillingPostalCode, RecordType.Name, Account_Annual_Revenue__c,
                        (SELECT Id, Contact__r.MailingStreet, Contact__r.MailingCity, Contact__r.MailingState, Contact__r.MailingPostalCode,
                        Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName, Contact__r.DOB__c, Contact__r.SS_Number__c, Ssn__c, 
                        Contact__r.percent_ownership__c, Contact__r.Phone, Contact__r.Salutation
                                FROM Personal_Guarantors__r WHERE Is_Guarantor__c = :true),
                        (SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
                                FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006R000000btQ3WIAU' LIMIT 1];
      return [SELECT Id,Name,FirstName__c,LastName__c 
            FROM PersonalGuarantor__c WHERE Opportunity__c = '006R000000dFdkSIAS'];
  }
}
```

right now it's showing the proper Personal Gaurantors in the record I'm using, but that's only because I hard coded the Opportunity__c to '006R000000dFdkSIAS'. How do I make the WHERE Opportunity__c = the master-record that my custom object is related to?

I thought it would be as simple as

```
FROM PersonalGuarantor__c WHERE Opportunity__c = opp.Id];
```

But that is not working. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track here but you need to ensure that your component passes the ID of the current record to the Apex controller to ensure it knows which record to query.

To do this, you need to begin (if you haven't already) by making the component understand the [Record context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-record-context.html) in which it is operating. To do this, simply include an @api decorated recordId property as follows:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default class TestClass extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
}
```

From here, you need to pass the recordId value to your Apex. You'll need to update the method to accept the ID as a parameter and use this in your SOQL query, for example:

```
public with sharing class DS_PGinFundingSource {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<PersonalGuarantor__c> getPGs(String recordId) {
      Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.DBA__c, Account.St_Incorp__c, Account.FederalTaxID__c, 
                          Account.Phone, Account.NAICS_Code__c, Account.BusinessStructure__c, Account.Mo_Year_business_started__c, 
                          Account.ShippingStreet, Account.ShippingCity, Account.ShippingState, Account.ShippingPostalCode, 
                          Account.BillingStreet, Account.BillingCity, Account.BillingState, Account.BillingPostalCode, RecordType.Name, Account_Annual_Revenue__c,
                          (SELECT Id, Contact__r.MailingStreet, Contact__r.MailingCity, Contact__r.MailingState, Contact__r.MailingPostalCode,
                          Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName, Contact__r.DOB__c, Contact__r.SS_Number__c, Ssn__c, 
                          Contact__r.percent_ownership__c, Contact__r.Phone, Contact__r.Salutation
                                  FROM Personal_Guarantors__r WHERE Is_Guarantor__c = :true),
                          (SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
                                  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :recordId LIMIT 1];
        return [SELECT Id,Name,FirstName__c,LastName__c 
              FROM PersonalGuarantor__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :recordId ];
    }
}
```

The last step is to update the JS that is calling your Apex in your component. If you're calling it. If you're using an [@wire method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-wire-method.html), it would look like this:

```
@wire(getPGs, { recordId: "$recordId" })
  PersonalGuarantors;
```

Whereas if you are calling [Apex imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-call-imperative.html), it should look like this:

```
getPGs({ recordId : this.recordId})
    .then((result) => {
        this.personalGuarantors = result;
        this.error = undefined;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
        this.personalGuarantors = undefined;
    });
```